# Replace specific characters in string using regex

Tags: java, regex

So I'm kind of new to regex and would like some help. I have dynamically generated input strings, a sample of which is:

```
(ACTOR > 0OR(PROC <> NULL AND REVIEW=NULL ANDFERDINAND = NAME ) )
```

Now I have to **replace `OR` with `|`, `AND` with `&`, `=` with `==` and `<>` with `!=` and provide a space between characters without them.**

Normally I could use `string.replace()` to do this. But, since the statement can come with or without spaces and even since `AND` can be present in other words as in the case of `FERDINAND`, i'm finding it a bit difficult.

Expected result:

```
( ACTOR > 0 | ( PROC != NULL & REVIEW == NULL & FERDINAND == NAME ) )
```

So I was wondering if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What if replace " AND " into " & " (with spaces around?)

Comment: And, is the original string `> 0OR` an error or just as is?

Comment: @GenoChen: For your first question, no that wont work. Because theres no guarantee that there will be space present before or after AND

Comment: Also `> 0OR` is just as it is. Thats why i mentioned there might or might not  be spaces before or after `AND` or `OR` in the string

Comment: I'm not sure if this is out of the "expressing ability" for regex. Maybe it needs to build a grammar tree for that (or I just make this question too complex?).

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("\\s*(?<![a-zA-Z])OR(?!\\s*[<>=!])\\s*", " | ")
.replaceAll("\\s*(?<![a-zA-Z])AND(?!\\s*[<>=!])\\s*", " & ")
.replaceAll("\\s*=\\s*", " == ")
.replaceAll("\\s*<>\\s*", " != ")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Your answer works fine. Would you mind putting it up as an answer with some explanations so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, but the case `ANDFERDINAND` cannot be handled. For this a regex is not suitable, because there is no simple criterion for where to separate.

```
String str2 = str1
      .replaceAll("([0-9])(?=[A-Z])", "$1 ")                 //1
      .replaceAll("\\bAND\\b", "&")                          //2
      .replaceAll("\\bOR\\b", "|")                           //3
      .replaceAll("(?<![=<>!])=(?!=)", "==")                 //4
      .replaceAll("<>", "!=")                                //5
      .replaceAll("(?<=[^&| ])(==|!=|&|\\)|\\|)", " $1")     //6
      .replaceAll("(==|!=|&|\\(|\\)|\\|)(?=[^ &|])", "$1 "); //7
```

First separate a number followed by a word character (positive look ahead).

Second an third substitute `AND` and `OR` at word boundaries.

Fourth substitute `=`, if it is not part of `==`, `!=`, `<=` or `>=` (negative look before and negative look ahead).

Fifth substitute `<>` (one simple match).

Sixth and seventh make that `==`, `!=`, `&`, `(`, `)` and `|` are surrounded by blanks, but do not add blanks at the beginning or end of the string. They will only be substituted unless immediately preceded or followed by `&` or `|`.

I did it only for uppercase letters. You can easily adapt, if you must also handle lower case letters.

Comment: For the string `CLASS_SUM >= 10 && COUNTRY != USA`, this is the output `CLASS__SUM > == 10 && COUNTRY ! == USA` which is wrong. Would you mind checking this?

Comment: Yes, this was not included in the original question, but it is easy to fix. I will modify my answer. Maybe, there are even more cases, when you extensively test. You should try to learn regex. It is not too hard to understand and you could modify the patterns for yourself.